# javascript jquery mobile create buttons in for-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, mobile

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    array.push($("<a href=\"#\" data-role=\"button\" data-inline=\"true\">" + i + "</a>"));
    $("#row").append(array[i]);
    array[i].click(function () {
        changeval(i);
        console.log(i);
    });
}
```

My problem is that the function changeval(i) becomes always the same value 10 of i.
I try to create buttons with onclick-function in this for-loop. I need a hint.

Comment: You need a closure for this, do this way http://jsfiddle.net/HUahz/ `i` is a shared variable in your case and it will have only the last value set by the for loop by  the time your handler is invoked.

Comment: add `$('[data-role=button]').button();` after appending anchors. updated @PSL demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/HUahz/2/

Answer (score 3):

I would separate the initial adding of the buttons and the 'click' action.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    array
            .push($("<a href=\"#\" data-role=\"button\" data-inline=\"true\">"
                    + i + "</a>"));
    $("#row").append(array[i]);
    array[i].click(function() {
        changeval(i);
        console.log(i);
    });
}
```

Would be split up to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    array.push("<a href=\"#\" data-role=\"button\" data-inline=\"true\">"
                    + i + "</a>");
    $("#row").append(array[i]);
};

$('#row').on('click', 'a', function() { 
    changeVal($(this).text());
    console.log($(this).text());
};
```

Also note that variables and functions within javascript should be written in CamelCaseForBetterReadability. Also note that I got rid of the $() surrounding the array items. Lastly, if you do not want to escape the quotations within your string, you can use a single quotation.

Answer (score 1):

Look into JS closures, the value of `i` is set to the last iteration of the loop. Wrap that in a self-executing func with `i` as the param:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        array
            .push($("<a href=\"#\" data-role=\"button\" data-inline=\"true\">"
                    + i + "</a>"));
        $("#row").append(array[i]);
        array[i].click(function() {
            changeval(i);
            console.log(i);
        });
    })(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a closure, e.g.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        array[i].click(function() { . . . } );
    )(i);
}
```

If you're using jQuery (seems like it if you're using `.click` :) you can use

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

to loop through elements and acheive this same functionality.

Comment: Down voter care to comment? I posted this answer _before_ anyone else did, so I really don't understand.